# What is a Recursive Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Recursive Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Recursive Words™ | Not Recursive Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SURVIVOR | SHIPWRECK |
| AGE | YEAR |
| MALARIA | AFRICA |
| FOREVER | ETERNITY |
| AUGUST | JULY |
| AGILE | SLOW |
| ONE | ZERO |
| SEQUENCE | SERIES |
| KEBAB | SANDWICH |
| SKY | SEA |
| PIANO | GUITAR |
| DECEMBER | NOVEMBER |
| ANOMALIES | ANOMALY |

The CSV version:

```
Recursive Words™,Not Recursive Words™
SURVIVOR, SHIPWRECK
AGE, YEAR
MALARIA, AFRICA
FOREVER, ETERNITY
AUGUST, JULY
AGILE, SLOW
ONE, ZERO
SEQUENCE, SERIES
KEBAB, SANDWICH
SKY, SEA
PIANO, GUITAR
DECEMBER, NOVEMBER
ANOMALIES, ANOMALY
```

These are not the only examples of Recursive Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint 1:

> I would have called them Golden Words™, but they exist already.

Comment: Just to confirm, does this puzzle follow the rule: "The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Recursive Word™ without relying on the other words."

Comment: Hmm...Every Recursive word has letters that can be removed to make a totally unrelated word. But a few of the non-recursive words have this property as well.

Comment: @MorganG What about SKY?

Comment: SK is the abbreviation for the Canadian province Saskatchewan... ;) Nah, it doesn't really fit, you're right.

Comment: @MorganG or Y, for y u do this :). It was a good thought.

Comment: There's no H, J, W, X, Z in recursive while in other Q, V, X, Z are missing.

Comment: @DavidFoong Yes it does. Sorry for the late reply, was away for the past 2 days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A recursive word is simply:

> A word whose letters add up to a number in the Fibonacci sequence. (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233...) A Not Recursive Word™'s letters do not add up to one of these numbers

For example...

> SURVIVOR: 19 + 21 + 18 +22 + 9 + 22 + 15 + 18 = **144**
> FOREVER: 6 + 15 + 18 + 5 + 22 + 5 + 18 = **89**
> ONE: 15 + 14 + 5 = **34**
> SKY: 19 + 11 + 25 = **55**
> AGE: 1 + 7 + 5 = **13**

Hint 1 would be more appropriate because...

> The Fibonacci sequence's growth is very similar to the Golden Ratio

It is called a Recursive Word™ because:

> the Fibonnacci sequence can be defined as a recursive function, meaning a function that calls itself in itself.

However...

> The Fibonnacci sequence can be adequatetly defined without recursion, so I'm not sure Recursive Word™ is the best defintion for these words! Golden Word™ would indeed be better.

I wonder what the longest Recursive Word™ is?

Comment: `incomprehensibilities` has 21 letters and a letter score of 233.

Comment: Chemistry to the rescue: "hydroxydehydrocorticosterone" has 28 letters and a score of 377. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm My dictionary had that as well, but it being a name and having the ability to create arbitrary long words for molecules made me dismiss it.

Comment: @wl: That's the drawback of such questions: You just run a search on a dictionary. It makes them boring to solve, although the search might yield some interesting results. (By the way, "incomprehensibilities" looks a bit artificial to me, too, as a plural of something that probably is a mass noun.)